# A riddle about a substance in a movie. (You will need to have seen it, sorry)

Tags: riddle, knowledge, movies

> I contain a deadly poison of powerful effect, Don't worry you'll be
>   safe from me, or so I should expect,
>
> My deadlyness is well reserved for beings otherworldly, For you I
>   could well be useful somewhat absurdly,
>
> The hero saw the answer sitting on a crowded table, He didn't know to
>   find me but not so clever students were able,
>
> I'll save the world with pseudo-science and not as you'd expect,  I
>   didn't even pay the crew that won me such respect.

What am I?

Comment: Why use code formatting instead of "quote"?

Comment: @nicael27  I could, I will.  I didn't know how to use quote formatting actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Head & Shoulders

And the movie (which I haven't seen but found descriptions online)

> Evolution

I contain a deadly poison of powerful effect,

> Head and Shoulders contains selenium in the form of selenium sulfide.

Don't worry you'll be safe from me, or so I should expect,

> It is generally not present in large enough quantities to be harmful to humans.

My deadlyness is well reserved for beings otherworldly,

> Head & Shoulders anti-dandruff shampoo is what is used to kill the aliens in the movie.

For you I could well be useful somewhat absurdly,

> Selenium sulfide kills the scalp fungus Malassezia, which causes shedding of dry skin fragments.

The hero saw the answer sitting on a crowded table,

> Ira figured out that selenium was poisonous to the aliens from its position on the periodic table.

He didn't know to find me but not so clever students were able,

> Much to Ira's surprise, his dumbest students Deke and Danny recalled than selenium sulfide is the active ingredient in Head & Shoulders.

I'll save the world with pseudo-science and not as you'd expect,

> The fact that selenium is poisonous to the aliens arises from analysis of the periodic table. They are nitrogen-based and the theory is that selenium will be poisonous to them as arsenic is to humans.

I didn't even pay the crew that won me such respect.

> Apparently, the movie crew received no money from Head & Shoulders for product placement.

Comment: Well done mate!  You got it.  Perfect explanations too.  I've been working at a P&G site that reminded me of the movie and this riddle just kind of happened.  Especially impressive that you got it without seeing the movie!  How wrong was I? +1